# Canonical Baggage Transfer question?

Tags: discussion, answers

We seem to be getting a lot of "will my bag be tranferred" type questions at the moment. Some do actually come with enough detail (around airlines and tickets) to answer, but many are very specific

Does someone fancy doing a canonical one? Mentioning interlining, one ticket vs many, within-alliance checking on 2 tickets in most cases, and the special case of the USA forcing you to collect and clear customs on first point of entry?

Comment: A very good idea, after seeing the "Electronics and Indian customs" question I am supporting this idea for any similar questions which people never stop while they are all almost the same.

Comment: I don't think USA is a special case. It is normal for a customs inspection to occur at the first point of entry in most countries outside Europe. And indeed it occurs at the first port of entry within the Scandinavian countries as well. Actually, I am struggling to think of any other countries outside Europe that do not do this on international->domestic.

Comment: @calchas The USA will make you do it on almost all Internationa->International connections too, which I think it rather unusual, as they don't offer airside international transit the way that most places do, which complicates things

Comment: @Gagravarr Aye, true enough.

Answer (score 1):

I very much like the idea but (a) don't feel qualified to volunteer (b) am not overly inclined to and (c) am not convinced exactly what I think you are asking would make a suitable canonical - that is be a single answer to a large number of questions we see here.

But a slight change in focus might work. Rather than attempting to be an answer to all of the myriad of subtle differences in scenario that are possible, rather describe what details may be required to give a 'proper' answer, preferably with reasons why. So for example:

We need to know which airport (even within USA the rules vary ...).
We need to know whether you want access during a layover/stopover or would prefer not to be burdened with luggage then.
We need to know how long is your layover/stopover (because duration can make a difference ...).
We need to know which airlines (because of interlining ...).
We need to know whether checked-through (already/possible ...)
We need to have some idea when you are flying (because the rules sometimes change ...).
and ...